# Git: How to list commits before specific SHA in reverse order?

Tags: git

My specific use case is that I want to see the latest release not including specific commit. I know of `git log --reverse`, `SHA..` and `..SHA`

Comment: *Before* has multiple meanings. Are you talking about date-and-time-stamps, or graph topology? If date-and-time-stamps, are you interested in the author ones, or the committer ones?

Comment: as they are currently ordered in the history on the particular branch. I guess that means `graph topology`

Comment: In that case, you probably want `git rev-list` (or `git log`, which is the user-facing variant) with the `--topo-order` option. This simply walks the graph, in topology order and backwards, emitting the commit hash IDs. Topological order *is* "backwards" although there's a decision point at each merge, which, when walking backwards, is a fork: `--topo-order` picks one side or other of the fork to walk first, then comes back to the side it didn't pick, without interleaving commits. Which side it walks first is tricky though: sorting options can help with tie-breaking here.

Comment: See also the `--first-parent` option, and remember that merges can technically have 3 or more parents, not just the usual 2.